# button tag is not working inside script tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the font size by clicking on button and using paragraph id

Trying to create a button which is on click will change the font size of my first javascript

code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="20px";' >click me</button>  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my output is coming : `JavaScript in Body`

actual output which i want to come:

```
JavaScript in Body
My First JavaScript
button(click me)
```

Comment: You can't put HTML inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Script tags targeting JavaScript (default) cannot contain HTML. I recommend opening your browsers console (F12) and viewing the errors as you are learning. It will help you immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the button out of the **script tag.**

it should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>
<button type="button" 
onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="20px";' >click me</button>  
<p id="demo">
</p>

</body>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button shouldn't be inside the script tag. Put it before or after the `</script>` tag.

Only JavaScript should be in the script tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="20px";' >click me</button>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because HTML isn't processed inside script tags, only JavaScript is allowed in there.